# use edge in node js to bind a DLL library not successful

Tags: .net, node.js, dll, jscript.net, edge.js

i try to learn how to use edge (a node.js module) to bind a pre-compiled DLL but it doesn't work in the right way...

my DLL is a really simple library and it has been tested multiple times in other .Net program.
i wrote my DLL file in Jscript.Net:

```
import System;
import System.Console;
import System.IO;

package power{

    public class testp {

            function hello (){

            var time_1 = DateTime.Now;

            for (var i =0; i<10000; i++){

                Console.WriteLine ("hello world!");

            };

            var time_2 = DateTime.Now;

            Console.WriteLine (time_2-time_1);

            };

    };

};
```

it is really simple, the Hello() method will print out 10000 "hello world" in stdout;

i can call it in other of my Jscript.net programs by doing:

```
import System;
import System.Console;
import System.IO;
import power;

var pri = new testp;
pri.hello();
```

according to the official web, i have tried:

```
var edge = require("edge");

var clrMethod = edge.func({
    assemblyFile: 'power.dll',
    typeName: 'power.testp',
    methodName: 'hello'
});

clrMethod();
```

MY QUESTION:
how can i call it in edge successfully?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Edge.js does not support JScript.NET. At least it doesn't mention it anywhere in the docs.

Have you tried [the example in C#](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#how-to-integrate-c-code-into-nodejs-code)? The problem is that Edge.js demands that the exported method in the DLL must have a specific signature:

`Func<object,Task<object>>`

Certainly your DLL is not exporting the function with the correct signature and that is the reason it didn't work as you expected.